# Two resource calls to the same service in the angular route resolver

Tags: java, angularjs, multithreading

I have a controller which has a resolver before the route is loaded. My resolver sets two constants : viewA and viewB. And both these constants are set by calling two different end points on the same service. The service calls the same db to retieve the data based on the id i pass through.

**Angular module**

```
 angular.module("ModuleA", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(["$routeProvider", "moduleResolver",
        function ($routeProvider, moduleResolver) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/route1', {
                    templateUrl: 'route1.html',
                    controller: "route1Ctrl",
                    resolve: moduleResolver
                })
                .when('/route2', {
                    templateUrl: 'route2.html',
                    controller: "route2Ctrl",
                    resolve: moduleResolver
                })
        }])
```

**Resolver**

```
angular.module("ModuleA")
    .constant("moduleResolver", {

        "viewA": ["moduleService", function(moduleService) {
            return moduleService.getResource("resourceA")
                .then(moduleService.mapResourceToViewA);
        }],
        "viewB": ["moduleService", function(moduleService) {
            return moduleService.getResource("resourceB")
                .then(moduleService.mapResourceToViewB);
        }]
    });
```

**Service**

```
angular.module("ModuleA")
    .service('moduleService', ['$q', '$resource',  
        function ($q, $resource) {

           this.getResource= function (resourceToCall) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $resource("url based on resourceToCall passed in", {}, {})
                        .get({}, function (result) {
                            defer.resolve(result);
                        },
                        function (result) {
                            defer.reject(result);
                        });
                return defer.promise;
           }

           this.mapResourceToViewA = function() {
             //map result from resource call to view model for View A
           }

           this.mapResourceToViewB = function() {
             //map result from resource call to view model for View B
           }

    }]);
```

I am getting an error when I try to do these calls in the resolver. Do i need to call a $digest() to resolve the first call beofre it triggers the next call. Should i be chaining the resource calls in the resolver. I would not prefer to do these as they are technically two separate models i want to keep separate and moreover i dont want to change the mapping methods to return promises.

Comment: After such a long description, you cannot miss a relevant detail, what is the error?

Comment: it is a 500 server error coming back from the second resource call to get resourceB, but the resource call works fine when i do the same call from the browser url. Am i missing something on the client and breaking the server.

Comment: i did a soapUI tests with parallel test suits and the server seemed to handle parallel requests. Any idea when i trigger multiple calls from the client, it seems to not work?

Comment: You should see the structure of you call that is failing and that is working fine. Maybe something send is incorrect.

Comment: Fixed the issue. It was a server side issue. My java service that was being triggered was then initiating another HTTP client connection. The java service was not configured to handle multiple connections. We ended up using the PoolingClientConnectionManager class, which solved the issue.